# is it possible to get group's images from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

is it possible to get group's images from facebook using facebook API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible see here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photos.get

The subj_id parameter you are passing to the Photos.get function needs to be the ID of the group.